# gnuplot ploting each series with different symbol

Tags: plot, gnuplot, series

I have a file with different series like:

```
x0_1 y0_1 A_0
x0_2 y0_2 B_0
...
x0_n y0_n N_0


x1_1 y1_1 A_1
x1_2 y1_2 B_1
...
x1_n y1_n N_1
```

If I do `plot "data.txt" u 1:2:3 w lp lc palette` I can plot all the series with different lines each. But how can I put a different symbol for each line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is divided into different series by two blank lines. If you give an index number 0, 1, 2 for each series, you can access the index number by `column(-2)` in `using` specification. The `column(-2)` is called 'pseudocolumns' in gnuplot. Please, see `help psuedocolumns` for details.

Here's an example script with this in mind.

```
set key noautotitle

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:7]

plot "test.dat" using 1:2:(column(-2)+1):(column(-2)+1)
                with linespoints ps 3 pt variable lc variable
```

[image]

In this example, the point types and line colors are assigned in order. However, if your gnuplot is an array-enabled version, you can also set the point type and line color as you wish, like this.

```
array pointtype[3] = [5, 7, 9]
array linecolor[3] = [1, 4, 6]

plot "test.dat" using 1:2:(pointtype[column(-2)+1]):(linecolor[column(-2)+1])
                with linespoints ps 3 pt variable lc variable
```

[image]

I used sample data like this,

```
1 1 5
2 1 6
3 2 4
4 3 5


1 2 7
2 3 5
3 3 4
4 4 2


1 3 6
2 4 4
3 4 3 
4 6 2
```

#### Addition: Legend

In this plot, the legend (or key) for individual lines cannot be displayed in a simple way. If you're using version 5.2.6 or later, you can use the keyentry style.

```
set key noautotitle

array pointtype[3] = [5, 7, 9]
array linecolor[3] = [1, 4, 6]

plot "test.dat" using 1:2:(pointtype[column(-2)+1]):(linecolor[column(-2)+1]) \
                with linespoints ps 3 pt variable lc variable, \
     for [i=0:2] keyentry with linespoints ps 3 pt pointtype[i+1] lc linecolor[i+1] \
                          title sprintf("series %i", i)
```

[image]

Comment: what about for the legend? Is it possible to also put the different symbols?

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: When adding the key is saying: "undefined variable: i" I tried to put i=0 before the plot, but neither it works. I'm using Version 5.2 patchlevel 1 for ubuntu. Is it only for newer versions?

Comment: for gnuplot 5.2.0 use for example: `plot "test.dat" using 1:2:(pointtype[column(-2)+1]):(linecolor[column(-2)+1]) w lp ps 3 pt var lc var notitle, \      for [i=0:2] '' u (NaN) w lp ps 3 pt pointtype[i+1] lc linecolor[i+1] title sprintf("series %i", i)`

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, here is a version which even works down to gnuplot 4.6 and with minor adaptions even with gnuplot 4.4. You can use `index` to address blocks (see `help index`).

**Code:** (using @binzo's `test.dat`)

```
### plot different sets (works with gnuplot 4.6)
reset 

myColor(i) = word("1 2 3",i+1)
myPts(i) = word("5 7 9", i+1)

set key top left
stats 'test.dat' u 1 nooutput   # get the number of blocks
plot for [i=0:int(STATS_blocks)-1] 'test.dat' u 1:2 index i \
     w lp ps 3 pt myPts(i) lc myColor(i) title sprintf("series %i", i)
### end of code
```

**Result:** (gnuplot 4.6)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer has already been accepted, but please allow me to put another (somewhat simpler) answer here.

You can successfully access each series of your data by specifying `index N` in the plot command (I forgot this point in the previous answer). This allows you to treat your data as if there are multiple datasets in a single file.

The script looks like this,

```
set key noautotitle

array pointtype[3] = [5, 7, 9]
array linecolor[3] = [1, 4, 6]

plot for [i=0:2] "test.dat" index i using 1:2 \
                            with linespoints ps 3 pt pointtype[i+1] lc linecolor[i+1] \
                            title sprintf("series %i", i)
```

Using your version of gnuplot, you'd still be able to show the plot including the legend in this way.